# What is the difference between Quartz Scheduler and Normal Java threads

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

What is the difference between Quartz Scheduler and Default Threads in Java ?

Comment: I think there is a bit of a mismatch between the two things that are compared. A normal thread scheduler simply switches between threads, whatever they are doing depending on the priority. A job scheduler on the other hand schedules higher level units of abstraction (the job) and allows them to run a specific time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quartz Scheduler is a complex solution for problems related to scheduling. It makes use of the core Java technologies to provide additional and more convenient functionalities. Consider it as a higher level framework with higher level of abstraction than the Thread concept.