# Quartz Scheduler vs TimerTask in JSF

Tags: jsf-2, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler, timertask

There are two type of task in my JSF2.0 web.

1. Invoke a third party java application only once at defined time
2. Invoke and get the data from some third party application repeatedly in some specified interval let say 2min

AFAIK JSF supports `Quartz Scheduler` but we have `TimerTask` in JavaSE. Can somebody explain me which API I should use in both the above mentioned cases and how? Any example code?
Thank you.

Comment: I found two links that might help you, I hope they do.  Here they are:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/11820017/259889

and

http://javapapers.com/core-java/java-timer/

Comment: Quartz is not part of Java SE/EE. It's just a 3rd party framework. TimerTask is a very bad idea in Java EE.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ApplicationScope bean that uses a TimerTask (sheduler), good or bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7499534/applicationscope-bean-that-uses-a-timertask-sheduler-good-or-bad)

Comment: and related, for JSP/Servlet, but applies to JSF as good: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15787605/how-to-run-a-background-job-method-at-fixed-intervals/15789574#15789574

Comment: @BalusC: Thanks ...I am looking into provided links.... thank you

Comment: @BalusC: One more question please. Can `ScheduledExecutorService` it fulfill point (1)? If yes how?